# Prove that P(B\A) = P(B) -P(A)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $$A \subset B$$
Using axioms of probability prove that $$P(B \setminus A) = P(B) - P(A)$$

Comment: What is the union of $A$ and $B \setminus A$? Are these two sets disjoint?

Comment: I know that $$P(B \setminus A) + P(A) = P(B)$$ but I don't see how I use any of the probability axioms here.

Comment: O wait never mind I got it.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Proofs

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$B=\{B\cap A\}\cup \{B\cap A^c\}$$
Hence  since the two sets are disjoint, the probability of the union is equal to the sum of probabilities.
$$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A^c)$$

And since the set $A$ is contained in $B$ the latter yields to:

$$P(B)-P(A)=P(B\cap A^c)$$

Comment: It doesn't really seem to help anything to insist on writing $B\cap A^c$ instead of $B\setminus A$ here ...

Comment: It's a matter of notation, and in my opinion is much more clear to understand why the sets are disjoint if you use the complement notation